# How to loop through matrix elements in mex c++ function for MATLAB?

Tags: c++, matlab, multidimensional-array, mex

I am trying to index write an external c++ function for MATLAB using mex to manipulate matrices, and am not able to use multidimensional indexing. There are examples provided [here](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/matlab_external/table-of-mex-examples.html), but I have not found how to fix the problem I describe below.
I have a sample matrix:

```
>> mat
mat =
 1    10
 2    20
 3    30
 4    40
 5    50
```

Currently I use a linear index through the matrix which works:

```
#include <mex.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[]) 
{ 
 //1.get pointer to input graph_list and allocate it    
    double *graph_list = mxGetPr(prhs[0]);
    mwSize mrows = mxGetM(prhs[0]);
    mwSize ncols = mxGetN(prhs[0]);  
    cout<< mrows<<" rows\n";
    cout<< ncols<<" cols\n";
    int mm, nn;
    for (nn=0;nn<ncols;nn++) {
        for (mm=0;mm<mrows;mm++){
            cout << graph_list[nn*(mrows) +mm]  <<"\n";            
        }
    }     
}
```

This produces:

```
>> mexTryAlex(mat)    
5 rows
2 cols
1
2
3
4
5
10
20
30
40
50
```

When I change the definition of graph_list and try 2D indexing to graph_list there is a  compilation error with `mex`:

```
double **graph_list = mxGetPr(prhs[0]);
cout << graph_list[nn][mm];
```

EDIT: here is the error message received

```
>> mex mexTryAlex.cpp
Warning: You are using gcc version "4.4.3-4ubuntu5)".  The version
     currently supported with MEX is "4.3.4".
     For a list of currently supported compilers see: 
     http://www.mathworks.com/support/compilers/current_release/
mexTryAlex.cpp: In function ‘void mexFunction(int, mxArray**, int, const mxArray**)’:
mexTryAlex.cpp:16: error: cannot convert ‘double*’ to ‘double**’ in initialization
mex: compile of ' "mexTryAlex.cpp"' failed.
??? Error using ==> mex at 208
Unable to complete successfully.
```

Comment: the compilation error being...?

Comment: Well, I guess since `mxGetPr(prhs[0])` is a pointer (and not a pointer-to-pointer), you're getting a 'double dereference' type of error or not?

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis, I added the error message in the *EDIT* I just put

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The compiler says it all.

In C, a 2D array is like an array of arrays. Therefore, a 2D array is fundamentally different from a 1D array; it's an array of pointers, in which each element contains a pointer to an array (hence a double-pointer, `double**`).

You're asking `mxGetPr()` to return a `double**`, but it returns a `double*`, e.g., a pointer to the first element of a 1D array. This 1D array can only be indexed *linearly*.

My guess is that MATLAB does this it this way to keep indexing arrays consistent -- would you really expect/want a `double****` for a 4-D array?

Moreover, `mxGetPr()` cannot be overloaded by return type (it's C after all).

In order to be able to double-index a 1D array, you could sneak in a little macro:

```
#define A(i,j) A[(i) + (j)*numrows]
```

and use it like so

```
double *A = mxGetPr(...);
int numrows = 4;   /* or get with mxGetM() or so) */

double blah = A(3,2); /* call to MACRO */
```

Obviously, as with all macros, there's a few things to look out for:

1. there's no bounds checking
2. C is 0-based, and Matlab 1-based, making *all indices different*
3. All arrays will have to be called 'A'

You could write a function to mitigate these drawbacks:

```
double getValue(double** array, int row, int* dims);
```

(or use `mxCalcSingleSubscript` as pointed out by [Shai](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16146795/1714410)), but that doesn't really improve expressive power IMHO:

```
double blah = getValue(array, 3,4, dims);
/* or the ugliness from mxCalcSingleSubscript(); */
```

You could also write in C++, make a Matrix-type class with an `operator()`, construct it with the pointer and dimensions from `mxGetPr()` and `mxGetDims()` etc., compile in Matlab using `g++` or equivalent, but that introduces a whole host of other problems and adds way much more complexity than needed for most cases.

Therefore, to avoid all of this mess, I just always compute the index in-place :)

Comment: @Vass: Glad to help. Often StackOverflow is the fastest and best solution for when you're stuck :)

Comment: I know this answer from last year, but I am having a hard time working out why it is `numRows/mxGetM` not `numCols/mxGetN` in `#define A(i,j) A[(i) + (j)*numrows]`

Comment: @SamuelO'Malley that's because the array has row-major ordering, that is, down the rows *first*, and down the columns *second*. So just break it down: if the array is 3×4, and you want to address the element on the second row, first column, then `i==1` (second row) and `j==0` (right?). When addressing the element on the first row, second column, `i==0` (first row) and `j==3` (it is "wrapped" with an offset equal to the number of *rows*, that stays constant for increasing `i`, until `i>2`).

Comment: Thanks @RodyOldenhuis, I was thinking that because it was C++ that it was column major ordering but I didn't realise that it was how MATLAB interprets it that matters.

Answer (score 7):

Having a matrix class is the by far easiest way to deal with this kind of problems. There are plenty to choose from so don't bother writing your own. Armadillo is fairly good and also integrates with LAPACK if you use that.
http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html

See example below

```
#include <mex.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <armadillo>
using namespace std;
using namespace arma;

//creates an armadillo matrix from a matlab matrix
mat armaMatrix(const mxArray *matlabMatrix[]){
    mwSize mrows = mxGetM(matlabMatrix[0]);
    mwSize ncols = mxGetN(matlabMatrix[0]);
    double *values = mxGetPr(matlabMatrix[0]);

    return mat(values, nrows, ncols);
}

void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[]) 
{
    mat graph_list = armaMatrix(prhs);

    //print the matrix
    cout << graph_list<<"\n";
    //print the first column
    cout << graph_list(span::all,0) <<"\n";
}
```

Comment: With slightly more code, it's also possible for Armadillo to directly use the memory of a Matlab matrix, ie. no copying.  See the docs [here](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#adv_constructors_mat)

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out by [Rody](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16146863/1714410), `mxGetPr` returns a pointer to a **1D** array. Therefore, you cannot treat it as a **2D** array in C++.
What you can do is use [`mxCalcSingleSubscript`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mxcalcsinglesubscript.html) function to convert **N-D** subscripts to a single 1D index.

Comment: @Sahi, I am not sure I understand. I want to used N-D subscripts but they don't work

Comment: @Vass - N-D subscripts in the C++ sense (i.e., `graph_list[mm][nn]`) will not work since `graph_list` is 1-D C++ array (regardless of the dimensionality of the `mxArray` from which it is derived). You may circumvent this restriction using `mxCalcSingleSubscripts` - see doc for this command for more details.